# Write a program that reads a file and writes out a new file with the lines in reversed order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reverse

> Write a program that reads a file and writes out a new file with the lines in reversed order (i.e. the first line in the old file becomes the last one in the new file.)

I am able to reverse the lines correctly using `reverse()` but I cannot get it to write the output to a new file. Here is the code that I have so far.

```
f = open("States.txt", "rb")
s = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newstates2.txt", "wb")
x = s.reverse()
f.write(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse()` doesn't return anything.  If you want to use `reverse()`, you have to use `s` afterward instead of making a new variable for the reversed list.  Also, `readlines()` returns a list, so you can't call `write()` on it directly, but you can iterate through it.  Here's an updated version:

```py
f = open("States.txt", "rb")
s = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("newstates2.txt", "wb")
s.reverse()
for line in s:
    f.write(line)
f.close()
```

Alternatively, you could use `reversed()` which does return the reversed version:

```py
for line in reversed(s):
    f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file = "<path to file>"
with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

reverse_file = "e:\\python\\reversed.txt"
with open(reverse_file, 'w') as rev:
    rev.writelines(lines[::-1])
```